# What is the meaning/benefit of this command: export PGOPTIONS="-P"

Tags: postgresql, psql

I see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html has

```bash
$ export PGOPTIONS="-P"
$ psql broken_db
...
broken_db=> REINDEX DATABASE broken_db;
broken_db=> \q
```

I see the below content, but I still did not understand.

> Alternatively, a regular server session can be started with `-P`
> included in its command line options. The method for doing this varies
> across clients, but in all `libpq-based` clients, it is possible to set
> the `PGOPTIONS` environment variable to `-P` before starting the client.
> Note that while this method does not require locking out other
> clients, it might still be wise to prevent other users from connecting
> to the damaged database until repairs have been completed.

What is the meaning/benefit of this command: `export PGOPTIONS="-P"`

Comment: Did you see this though: "To recover safely, the server must be started with the -P option, which prevents it from using indexes for system catalog lookups".

Comment: I don't understand reference document, also your explain.

Comment: Did you see this part? "In this case it's important for the system to not have used any of the suspect indexes itself."  I don't understand how that could be clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `-P` option tells the server to start [without using indexes for system catalog lookups](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-reindex.html):

> To recover safely, the server must be started with the -P option, which prevents it from using indexes for system catalog lookups.

This is needed if you are attempting to recover from a corrupted index on a system table.  If you are not attempting to recover from corruption, you won't need this option, and in fact should not use it since it will reduce server performance under normal circumstances.